# view in mvc can not render html for the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

when I try to render HTML in view for the second time the  HTML not change and nothing happens it  still  as it aims calling the same view two times when  the modal is empty and when I fill modal with data and then try to render it 
this is the view

```
  <section class="col-12 m-b-60">
    <h2 class="m-b-20">Deduction</h2>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-text">
                        <span class="label">Employee ID</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID ..."id="employeid">
                    </label>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="veiwemployee()">
                        Get
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<section class="col-12 m-b-20">
`@if (Model != null)`
    {
      @await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Home/View.cshtml", Model);
    }
</section>
```

The action

```
public IActionResult EmployeeDeduction(int employeeID = 0)
        {
            Deduction deduction = new Deduction() ;
            if (employeeID == 0) { }
            else
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                deduction = _conn.GetEmployeByEmployeeID(employeeID);
            }
            return View("/Views/view.cshtml",deduction);
        }
```

The Js function

```
function veiwemployee() {
    if ($("#employeid").val() == "") {
        $("#employeid").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/EmployeeDeduction?employeeID=' + $("#employeid").val(),
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the  veiwemployee() function that you are calling ?

Comment: also where are you rendering the second time. I didn't understand

Comment: veiwwmployee()  js function to call the action again with the employee id to  enter the else condition  with the data of the employee

Comment: that is the function which is rendering the view again right ? can you show me the code for that function?

Comment: If you're expecting something to happen twice, can you set a breakpoint in either the controller or the view? That way you can see whether the code is actually executing a second time.

Comment: `function veiwemployee() {

        if ($("#employeid").val() == "") {
            $("#employeid").style.borderColor = "red";
        }
        else {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/EmployeeDeduction?employeeID=' + $("#employeid").val(),
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (resp) {


                }
            });
        }



    }`

Comment: @ScottHannen it execute but not rendering my html

Comment: Is the server-side code hitting the breakpoint? If it's not, that's the problem. If it is getting hit, make sure that the controller action is returning something. If it is, look at the Chrome debugger tools, inspect the response, and make sure there's something in the response that looks like what you expect. And if it does look right, then the problem is likely in the JS. The challenge is that there are so many links in the chain and the problem could be in any one of them, so you may need to eliminate them one at a time.

Comment: you are not appending the response anywhere in the function

inside function(resp){
 // append 
}

Answer (score 0):

this tag does not have closing.

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID ..." id="employeid">
```

"/" missing

Comment: yes trying to render  my data in the same view but not working also so t  assume the issue was that  i used the same view twice  after each other

Comment: are you trying to render the Employee or the Deduction? maybe there could be some conflict since you can render only one model at a time.